# CakePHP 3.9 'append' <span> element in parent <div>?

Tags: html, cakephp

I'm new to CakePHP but I was recently tasked with upgrading some old CakePHP code (2.0) to a later version (3.9). I'm stuck at a point where I'm trying to append a span element to a div element. This is how the code appears in the web UI using the following CakePHP 2.0 code below:

[image: CakePHP 2.0 Web UI Output]

`$nmeaOpts .= $this->Panel->nestedRow([ $this->Panel->text($this->Widget->input( 'output_nmea_rate' , ['label' => __('Output Rate'), 'append' => __('Hz')] )) ]);`

In inspect element, I can clearly see the appended  "add-on" element existing within the "input-append" div element.
[image: CakePHP 2.0 Inspect Element]

However, in CakePHP 3.9, the same above code gives this output in the web UI:

[image: CakePHP 3.9 Web UI]

As you can see, the appended element exists on a new line from the div "input-append" element. Upon inspecting element, I can see that with CakePHP 3.9, the above code puts the `<span class="add-on">Hz</span>` *outside* of the `<div class="input-append">` element. How do I get the appended `<span class="add-on">` to exist within the "input-append" div element?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'll post what allowed me to overcome this issue after I shamelessly deleted the question:

`$nmeaOpts .= $this->Panel->nestedRow([ $this->Panel->text($this->Widget->input( 'output_nmea_rate' , ['label' => __('Output Rate'), 'type' => 'number', 'append' => __('Hz')] )) ]);`

I don't know if it's specific to Cake 3.9, but I had to specify `'type' => 'number'` to this WidgetHelper, and voila:

[image: CakePHP 3.9 Web UI]

Without specifying the type, it defaulted to type text.